# vshost32.exe crash when calling unmanaged DLL

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005, unmanaged, vshost32

I'm using a VS 2005 app to interface against an unmanaged (Fortran) DLL. When I run the compiled executable straight from the command line, everything is fine - the DLL can be accessed, and I can work with the functions in the DLL.

Unfortunately, when I launch the app from VS 2005, I get a popup stating "vshost32.exe has stopped working" and no useful debugging information.

Has anyone experienced this behavior, or know why this might be occuring? I can't figure out why it would run fine when launched stand-alone, but not via vshost32.

(One last note: I am using .local files to force registered dlls to be used from cwd, but this particular dll is not registered. I'm just noting it here in case it helps.)

---

Thanks very much,

Mike

Comment: Sadly, no. I've tried everything from modifying calling conventions to writing a C wrapper around the Fortran, then wrapping that! *Sigh* Good luck to you, though, and if you get any results, please do leave an answer below! Thx :)

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Did you find any solution or workaround for it?

Answer (score 22):

I had problem with crashes of vshost32.exe the problem vanished when I checked the checkbox:

`Properties -> Debug -> Enable unmanaged code debugging`

Does it work for you?

**EDIT:** In more recent versions the option is called: `Enable native code debugging` (thanks Qwerty01)

**EDIT:** It also seems to help in VS2008 (@Deacon Frost), VS2010 (@Alxandr).

Comment: This fixed my vshost32.exe crashing problem.

Comment: This caught an error in some unmanaged fortran code that was crashing my program. Good tip.

Comment: I was fighting this all day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can disable use of the visual studio hosting process from Properties -> Debug

Comment: Surprisingly, had no effect - still crashes in the same way. Do you know what exact effect this setting has? I think vshost is still used, but the <appname>.vshost.exe isn't used.

Comment: Thanks for the help - still crashing, but I appreciate the debugging help!

Answer (score 1):

Might be that there is an unhandled exception. You could try to add the following code to handle all uncatched exceptions:

```
static void Main()
{
  // Add a handler for the UnhandledExceptionEvent
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
     (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", 
              MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.Exit();  
    }
}
```

The reason for the underlying problem is that you might have a different working folder when debugging so that your native library is not found.

Comment: Unfortunately, no unhandled exceptions were caught. Also, I'm setting the cwd explicitly in code before the calls to the unmanaged dll. Still baffled! Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: It assume that the external dll is already resolved before you have the chance to change the working folder. I couldn't find any documentation when this resolution happens but it might be at the time the assembly is jitted?

Comment: Well, the really strange thing is that I can call _some_ of the functions in the unmanaged DLL, just not all of them. erk!

Comment: Maybe you have a different version of the dll on your path during runtime? Or certain funtions in your dll load other libraries dynamically which are not on your path during runtime

Comment: Not a bad suggestion. I did a bunch of trial & error stuff, and I've decided that I'm just gonna run the dang thing outside of Visual Studio. I can't debug this particular piece of the app, but life goes on. thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express. I was able to stop the vshost32 crashes by navigating to Project ->  Properties. I clicked on the Debug tab and unchecked the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

download dependency walker
http://www.dependencywalker.com/
use it to open up your dll, and see if it relies on other dlls that are not present in that folder.

Comment: thx for the suggestion! unfortunately, as it runs fine from command line, I can rule out a dependency issue - there's just something about using the .vshost. executable that is mucking up somewhere. *sigh*!