# vshost32.exe has stopped working while executing ssis package from windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created an ssis package. Tested it by executing directly and it is working fine. But when executing it by a windows application, getting an error message "vshost32.exe has stopped working" and application get closed. Any idea?

[image]

This is my code:

```
pkgLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSISPath"].ToString();
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
pkg.ImportConfigurationFile(@"C:\SSIS\Config\My_Config.dtsConfig");
DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

This is my system configurations:
Win 7 32 bit
SQL Server 2008
Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Anything in the event viewer? Do you have any logging?

Comment: Event viewer shows:

"Faulting application name: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba2084b"

Faulting module name: DTS.dll, version: 2007.100.2531.0, time stamp: 0x49cfb3a9
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Comment: There are several [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vshost32.exe+has+stopped+working) about this error. One person found a [specific solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735621/vshost32-exe-crash-when-calling-unmanaged-dll), others just re-installed.

Comment: If you could also review your [previously asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/194450/jobi?tab=questions&sort=newest) and mark any as answered, it would help improve StackOverflow for future searchers.