# Passing Data in and out of a DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, dll, pass-by-reference

I am attempting to create a C# program that can pass data into a C/C++ DLL, store the data, and complete calculations on it.  The result would then be returned to the C# program.  The reason for not using C# for the calculations is that I am planning to accelerate it with CUDA.

I currently declaring a byte array in C#, and passing that as an argument to the DLL to send data.

I then declare a byte array of the same size in C# and pass it as an argument to receive the data.  The DLL should then write the results into that memory.

When I run the program, the correct numbers get printed to the screen.  (As I am writing 1,2,3... to the array twice, the addition of these is 2,4,6...)  "The cat chased the mouse" is then printed.  When I press a key, "The mouse chased the cat" is displayed, and the program crashes before it exits displaying a vshost32.exe stopped working error.
I was able to solve this error from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735621/vshost32-exe-crash-when-calling-unmanaged-dll).

Now when I attempt to run the EXE directly from windows explorer, I get the number 36 printed as the first step, but then I get the following error on the compute function call:

> "Unhanded exception: System.AccessViolationException Attempted to read
>   or write protected memory.  This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt"

I know the DLL loaded correctly because the init function returned the correct number.  I am not sure why it would only be crashing when I am running it as an EXE and not in the debugger.  What could be causing this?

Is there a different way I should be handling the memory exchange between the DLL and the C# program?  My goal is to avoid copying it using a Marshal Copy as I need this to be high performance.  The end goal would be the DLL copying the memory to or from the GPU and the GPU doing the calculations, so I see no reason to have it copied a 2nd time in the DLL before going to the GPU.

C++ DLL Code (written as C code)

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "stdlib.h"
const int CONSTANT = 3;
char** items;
int itemCount = 0;
int xcnt = -1;
int ycnt = -1;

extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall init(int itemcount_local, int xcnt_local, int ycnt_local){
    itemCount = itemcount_local;
    xcnt = xcnt_local;
    ycnt = ycnt_local;
    items = (char**)malloc(itemCount);
    if (items == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
        items[i] = (char*)malloc(CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt);
        if (items[i] == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        for (int d = 0; d < CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt; d++){
            items[i][d] = 0;
        }
    }
    return CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt;
}

//frees the memory created in init
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall cleanup(){
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
        free(items[i]);
    }
    free(items);
    return;
}

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall loadItem(int index, char* data){
    memcpy(items[index], data, CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt);
    return;
}

//fills the buffer with the computed result.  Buffer needs to be the size of CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall compute(char* buffer){
    for (int x = 0; x < CONSTANT*xcnt*ycnt; x++){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
            sum += items[i][x];
        }
        if (sum > 255){ //saturate at 255
            buffer[x] = 255;
        }
        else {
            buffer[x] = sum;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

C# code

```
class Program
{
[DllImport("DllTest1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int  init(int imagecount_local, int xres_local, int yres_local);

[DllImport("DllTest1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void cleanup();

[DllImport("DllTest1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void loadItem(int index, byte[] data);

[DllImport("DllTest1.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void compute(byte[] buffer);

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int x = 4, y = 3;
    int total = x * y * 3;
    Console.WriteLine(init(5, x, y));

    byte[] a = new byte[total];

    compute(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
    }

    byte[] b = new byte[total];
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (byte)i;
    }
    loadItem(0, b);
    loadItem(1, b);

    compute(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
    }

    //cleanup();
    Console.WriteLine("The cat chased the mouse");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("The mouse chased the cat");
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: we need to see your code to understand the problem and try to help you out

Comment: Opps, I was still typing, and must have accidentally submitted it.  I am still typing the question on another tab.  Weird.

Comment: As a informational note, you can accelerate C# calculations on gpu using Hybridizer for example. Disclaimer : I work on the develop of that software.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem.  The line

```
items = (char**)malloc(itemCount);
```

should have been

```
items = (char**)malloc(itemCount*sizeof(char*));
```